# iframe api for multiple videos

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I have a slideshow with youtube video's. But the problem now is that I can't trigger the `onPlayerStateChange`.
This is my code:

```
echo '<iframe id="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/kOkQ4T5WO9E?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&rel=0</iframe>';
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
<script src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('youtube', {
            events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
        });
    }

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";

    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data === 0) {
            alert('Video finished, next slide');
            slide.next();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to reload the iframe api when the video has ended?

Comment: well, at least it is not `java` code :)

Comment: @Andrii Abramov Haha thanks!, I'II change it.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, as last I knew, the YouTube API was entirely deprecated and almost no longer supported.

You're going to need to load new videos with the `loadVideoByUrl` function

```
player.loadVideoByUrl(mediaContentUrl:String,
                      startSeconds:Number,
                      suggestedQuality:String):Void
```

Also, you should change `event.data === 0` to `event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED`

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, Do you mean? <embed id="youtube". .. . .. . .</embed>?

Comment: @HenkErtje Other than reloading the page, I dont think there is a way. You could try saving some data in cookies, however, and pick up where you left off. There isn't a whole lot of info for me to work off of, though, so I'm not sure what you're doing exactly

Comment: I'm trying to program the iframe api like, that multiple videos is triggered on the same page. When I start the slideshow The first video plays.... when the video ends I get a alert: finished. then the slideshow slides to the next video. (everthing will be the same only the youtubeID change).

Comment: I'm confused where your issue lies now... in your question, you say: "the problem now is that I can't trigger the `onPlayerStateChange`". Does the `alert` trigger, or can you not get the `alert` to run? If you get the `alert`, I'll need to see what `slide.next()` is

Comment: Oh huh? I changed the question... I'm sorry but just wonder to know to reload the iframe api when the next video appears

Comment: @HenkErtje You cannot.